# "Problem with <person>" vs. "Problem of <person>"

Tags: phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

The original sentence is below:

> The problem **with** my other half is that he has no ambition.

If I use the word 'of' instead of 'with', how does the meaning of the sentence change? When should I use 'of' instead of 'with'?

Answer (score 5):

When using **Joe's** problem (or "the problem **of Joe**"), you are discussing **Joe** (and his problem). Perhaps he has some medical condition.

When using "the problem **with** Joe" (or perhaps "**my problem with** Joe"), you are discussing **yourself**, and the difficulty you have with Joe. Perhaps you can't understand his accent.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following dictionary definition (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**with**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/with)
>   PREPOSITION
>
> **7** In relation to.
>   *"my father will be angry with me"*

That is, a *problem with (someone)* is a problem that you have or which exists generally in relation to that person. Usually it will be a problem with their behaviour, their attitude, or some other characteristic they have.

Saying a *problem of (someone)*, on the other hand, means that the problem is the peson's—a problem they experience, rather than anyone else. Consider this definition:

> [**of**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of)
>   PREPOSITION
>
> **3** Indicating an association between two entities, typically one of
>   belonging, in which the first is the head of the phrase and the second is
>   something associated with it.
>   *"the son of a friend"*
>   *"the government of India"*
>   *"a photograph of the bride"*
>   *[with a possessive] "a former colleague of John's"*

Your sentence as-is wouldn't sound natural if you substituted "of" for "with". Instead, I would write it as:

> 1. A problem of my other half's is a lack of ambition.
> 2. My other half's problem is a lack of ambition.

Even still, sentence #1 here isn't great, and I would prefer sentence #2. I can't think of a natural-sounding sentence like #1 where a possessive (`'s`) isn't used.